# Changing background colour of clicked date (Fullcalendar) React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar and trying to change colour of selected date.

How I intend to do it:

- setState selected date.
- pass it as props to events object of fullcalendar.
- Change color of selected date cell by setting  Event Object’s display background property.

I am able to get the required result except for the background color part.

Here is the [link to calendar](https://testliffdatethighlight.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/index.html)

As you can see, there is a little check on date you have clicked.

What I want to  do is to change the background colour of that cell.

Pretty much shown [here on the right side demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events)

Here is the code for fullcalendar:-

```
<FullCalendar
  timeZone="Asia/Tokyo"
  plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
  initialView="dayGridMonth"
  headerToolbar={{
    start: "prev",
    center: "title",
    right: "next",
  }}
  height="100%"
  locale="ja"
  aspectRatio={0.7}
  dateClick={(dateArg: DateClickArg) => {
    this.props.dateSelect(dateArg.date);
  }}
  longPressDelay={1}
  dayCellContent={function (arg: DayCellContentArg) {
    return arg.date.getDate().toString();
  }}
  events={[
    {
      title: "✔️",
      allDay: true,
      start: this.getSelectedDate(),
      end: this.getSelectedDate(),
      borderColor: "white",
      backgroundColor: "pink",
      display: "background",
    },
  ]}
  editable={false} 
  selectable={true} 
/>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In your event you can give color option also you can use eventClick to detect event on events it returns current event and its element you can make changes on it accordingly

Comment: If you use the "select" feature instead of dateClick then it automatically puts a background on the selected area. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting

Comment: @ADyson, thankyou for reply.
I had working version of what you said and selected date's background color would be set by setting css for --fc-highlight-color.
But for some reason, background property stopped working.(most probably after i set height to 100%)
Also, selected date needs to be highlighted on page render which does not happen by select feature.

Comment: "selected date needs to be highlighted on page render"...surely at the point the page is rendered, no-one has selected a date yet? Have I misunderstood? And I'm not sure how setting the height could affect the background colour of a selection...are you certain that's the issue? Did you remove the height again to test it?

Comment: @ADyson, Yes i tried to remove height but no luck.
The problem started when i tried to change the layout of the page.
Thankyou again for your reply.

Comment: @VikasKandari, thankyou for your comment.
Unfortunately what you suggested did not work either.
i tried to give event a className property and thereby changing its background colour by setting css for that className. I was able to see the class being applied to date with event but for some reason background color did not change.

Comment: @ADyson, sorry there was less explanation for the use case. The date user clicked needs to stay highlighted if user decides to come back to the calendar page.For example, from the [link](https://testliffdatethighlight.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/index.html) , select any date, then move to another page using button at the right bottom, then from that page come back to calendar page by clicking the bottom black button. You will see that the selected date stays selected.

Comment: "The problem started when i tried to change the layout of the page"...ok then probably somewhere in the CSS of your page there is something conflicting or overriding the fullCalendar CSS. You'll need to debug it carefully, possibly with trial and error .the browser developer tools can help you though by showing you what CSS rules are applied to an element

Comment: @ADyson, yes probably that is the case. Only I haven't been able to find anything wrong. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou everyone for kind responses.

As @ADyson pointed out it was my css messing with fullcalendar css.

I had following in my css:

```
html,
body,
div {
  position: relative;
}
```

It caused fc-bg-event class to inherit height of its parent class whose value was 0px, which made it look like there was no color in the background.

Everything worked out fine after I removed div from above code.

Answer (score 2):

To change Event Color just simply supply color option in event object

```
<FullCalendar
  timeZone="Asia/Tokyo"
  plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
  initialView="dayGridMonth"
  headerToolbar={{
    start: "prev",
    center: "title",
    right: "next",
  }}
  height="100%"
  locale="ja"
  aspectRatio={0.7}
  dateClick={(dateArg: DateClickArg) => {
    this.props.dateSelect(dateArg.date);
  }}
  longPressDelay={1}
  dayCellContent={function (arg: DayCellContentArg) {
    return arg.date.getDate().toString();
  }}
  events={[
    {
      title: "✔️",
      allDay: true,
      start: this.getSelectedDate(),
      end: this.getSelectedDate(),
      color: "red",
    },
  ]}
  editable={false} 
  selectable={true} 
/>
```

example event object below

```
events={[
    {
      title: "✔️",
      allDay: true,
      start: this.getSelectedDate(),
      end: this.getSelectedDate(),
      color: "red",//This will set the color
    }
]}
```

this will change background color of event you don't ned special CSS or anything

Still if you programmatically want to change the background color of event then bind a event handler on each event by using **eventDidMount** callback, this function will be fired after appending each event element so you can simply change event css or element programmatically.

```
<FullCalendar
  eventDidMount={(dateArg: DateClickArg) => {
     console.log(dateArg.el); //this will return event element
  }},
  events={[
    {
      title: "✔️",
      allDay: true,
      start: this.getSelectedDate(),
      end: this.getSelectedDate(),
      color: "red",
    },
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer.
Your answer changes the background color of 'event', which happens to have block property as such only a part of date cell containing event gets colored.
What i need is to colour the background of date cell containing event.
As shown [here] (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) on the right side demo.
The event also has background property which is supposed to work the way needed here but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to people trying to change dates or events on click:

```
<FullCalendar
  ...
  // Could be `dateClick`
  eventClick={async (selected) => {
    const event = selected.event

    event.setProp("backgroundColor", "red")
  }}
/>
```